# img load goes into infinite loop in IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, infinite-loop, jquery-load

I have the following code in my page, which works fine on all browsers (even on IE9), but not on IE7 and IE8:

```
$.each($('.cic img'), function(index, value) {
  $(this).load(function() {
     // infinite loop here in IE7 and IE8
  });
});
```

The HTML is:

```
            <div class="cic">
                <img wicket:id="image1" class="image1" />
            </div>
                            ...
            <div class="cic">
                <img wicket:id="image2" class="image2" />
            </div>
```

The reason for this is that on IE7 and IE8 the load function goes into an infinite loop and I end up with the message: 'This page became unresponsive due to a long running script'.

**EDIT:** Changing the the selector to $('.cic img').each() did not help. I also confirmed that loadImageCropper() is not the cause of the problem. I also typed $('.cic img').lenght before the above script, and it returned 2, which is correct.

**The above script and HTML are being loaded with AJAX.**

I'll appreciate any help!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `loadImageCropper`, and why is it inside your `each` loop?

Comment: it is a function that initializes imgAreaSelect plugin for jQuery, for each image that matches the criteria, but it's not relevant to the loop. It doesn't cause it.

Comment: Did you take it out and try it? I wonder if updating your initial `each` to `$('.cic img').each()` would solve it... not sure how the .each selector iterates but maybe it's reselecting?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ specifically warns against using `.load` on images for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @hunter: editing the each function did not solve the problem, nor removing the loadImageCropper call did mblaze75, as far as I see in this document there may be a problem if the images are already loaded in the document at the time load() is being called. But this is not the case here. Images are not loaded by the page when the above script is being called. Thank you

Comment: using .load will not work consistently across all browsers as far as cached images vs non cached images. I suggest using an image preloader that already takes that into account. However, I don't think that would cause the problem you are having. the problem you are having sounds almost like an infinite loop or too much processing is being done for the browser to handle it, however you are only dealing with 2 images. I suggest removing parts of the code until you find which part causes the issue.

Comment: For a more scientific approach to debugging, suggest using Firebug to set breakpoints and step through the code.

Comment: @Tentonaxe, look at the post change I made. Andrew, the problem is with IE7 and IE8, so I can't use Firebug. I can't even use the IE debug tool, since the above JS and HTML are loaded with AJAX and therefore I can't set breakpoints of dynamically inserted code.

Comment: Yeah I realised after posting that comment you were in the IE world. But this does lead to a wider issue of how to debug such client-side scripts. Seems like the the Javascript development environment is lacking in this area.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and managed to isolate it to the image preloader plugin. It's odd, because I have used it before in other projects on IE7 with no issues. I'm going to try my old vanilla JS preloader and see if it solves the issue; I'll post it here if it works.

Answer (score 0):

As with the [script element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180173), IE8 and under fire legacy [readyStateChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa743099) events rather than standard load events for img src updates, so the load event masks the fact that the event is not recognized. The solution is to fork the code before the event binding:

```
function imageSwap()
  {
  var $img = $('.cic img');

  if(!!document.addEventListener)
    {
    $img.on("load", loadTest)
    }

  else
    {
    $img.get(0).attachEvent("onreadystatechange", loadTest);
    } 

  function loadTest(event)
    {
    $img.show();
    }
  }
```